# Spinlock for a two thread enviroment

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, operating-system, locking

I am trying to implement an optimized spinlock for a two-thread environment, where one thread is very likely to run, and the second thread is unlikely to run.

My thoughts:

#define LOCK(lock) 
while (likely(AtomicReadIfEqualWrite8(&lock, 0, 1)));

#define UNLOCK(lock) 
AtomicWrite8(&lock, 0);

Since we only have one thread likely to run, we could give the compiler a hint to evaluate the boolean condition in the while loop as true.
thus, if the second thread is run, which is unlikely, the penalty will be still worth it.

Any suggestion for further optimizations?

Thanks

Comment: I am not qualified to say what happens if you provide branch hints for a conditional that depends on an atomic variable, but I wonder about the premise of your question. Are you saying that the probability of the mutex being locked at any given moment in time depends on which thread wants to lock it next? How could that be true? Also, are you saying that there is _ever_ a time when the probability of the mutex being locked is greater than half? If that's true, then you might want to seriously reconsider the architecture of your program.